# Mysql search forward slash / in a query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a simple query in a table searching for a / in certain position without luck.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`path`, 40, 40) LIKE '%/%'
FROM files
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: `LIKE` is used with `WHERE` ... you can't use it in `SELECT`

Comment: Do you want the position where / occurs?

Comment: substring(`path`, 40, 40) means start from index 40 till 40 characters, do you mean start from first character for 40 characters in that case substring(`path`,0,40)

Comment: Yes, my fault, bad day for me... thank you!

Comment: no problem, next time try telling us what to do and the what have you tried to accomplish it, that way can tell if you are on the right path or not and give more precise answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this (provided, if you know the position where / will be present)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`path`, 40, 40) as slashpath  FROM files 
where SUBSTRING(`path`, 40, 40) LIKE '%/%'
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be?

```
SELECT *
FROM files
WHERE SUBSTRING(`path`, 40, 40) LIKE '%/%'
```

Comment: Works but some results doesn't match the position of /, i can't understand why.

Comment: what do you mean "don't match the position of /"? The query will return all rows where column 'path' have a / from the 40th position to the 80th.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`path`, 40, 40) path  
FROM files 
where substring(`path`, 40,40) like '%/%'
```